# How can i make the editText get the value of stringarray if the user enter certain keyword and display it?

Tags: java, android

Good day, I am making a Quiz App that need to type to answer and Im new in programming.
I want to know how or if it is possible to answer the question correctly if they not get the exact answer.

because the given questions have an answer in sentence form for example :

Q. "What are the 3 main parts of the Tree?"
A. "The 3 main parts are branch, leaves, root."

If they only answer "Branch, leaves, root," I'm gonna make it correct and display the exact answer to the same editText or to Textview or to some pop-up message . I think I'm gonna need another ArrayList for the keyword only?
What is the code in this kind of thing?
I have for more than 300 Q/A btw.

This is my editText:

```
           answer1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            mp2.start();
            switch (category) {
                case "Basic":
                    if (answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(BasicList.get(level).getbasicans1())) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
```

And This is my Array List.

```
         final ArrayList<BasicItem> BasicList = new ArrayList<>();
    BasicList.add(new BasicItem("What is the Figurative meaning of [1]Water, [2]Field, [3]Fire?", "Word as as ds ds", "Example of example only", "Word that consume"));
    BasicList.add(new BasicItem("What is the meaning of [1]B,[2]D,[3]S?", "Betrayal", "Destruction", "Salvation");
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. You can try this

```
String sentence = "Check this answer and you can find the keyword with this code";

String search  = "keyword";

if ( sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) != -1 ) {

   System.out.println("I found the keyword");

} else {

   System.out.println("not found");

}
```

OR

```
if ( d.contains("hello")) {
            System.out.println("I found the keyword");
}
```

OR , if you want to use string matching,

```
if (d.matches(".*Hey.*")) {
    c.setText("OUTPUT: SUCCESS!");
} else {
    c.setText("OUTPUT: FAIL!");  
}
```

.* -> 0 or more of any characters

Hey -> The string you want

Comment: i watched some pattern matching tutorial but i cant figure how can i use that from my prob. Can u give me a sample code please ? . also why should i use textWatcher?